# scrapy avoid to extract text inside iframe with xpath

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

i have this code
`loader.add_value('article_content', response.xpath( "//div[@class='entry-content']//text()[not (ancestor-or-self::script or ancestor-or-self::noscript or ancestor-or-self::style or ancestor-or-self::figure or ancestor-or-self::iframe)]").extract())`

seems to work well but not for iframe tag
`ancestor-or-self::iframe`

as it gets the text inside the iframe, how to avoid to extract iframe text
thanks a lot

i tried to avoid to extract iframe content but it returns the text inside the iframe tag

Comment: I can't see why the `iframe` case would not work, sorry. It's a puzzle. But for simplicity you should just use the `ancestor` axis rather than the `ancestor-or-self` axis, because by definition a text node (i.e. a node identified by your `text()` expression) is not an element and therefore cannot be one of the elements whose content you are trying to exclude.

Comment: For better help, please provide a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I am certain that if you were to post a [mre] that someone would be able to come up with a more intuitive and readable selector.